# Get Email contact list from Google Apps Directory?

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there any other way I can access to the email contacts under Google Apps Directory in Google Apps Script?

As I had tried the alternative way: UserManager.getAllUsers() in Google Apps Script to access user info but then faced access permission.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for UserManager says

> This class allows administrators to create, update, retrieve and delete users in a Google Apps domain. To use this class you have first to enable the Provisioning API on your domain. For a next-generation control panel, enable the API by logging in to your admin account, and select Domain settings and the User settings tab to select the checkbox enabling the Provisioning API. If your control panel is not Next generation, enable the API by logging in to your admin account, and clicking the Users and groups tab. Then click the Settings subtab, select the checkbox to enable the Provisioning API and save your changes.

Can you confirm that you have the next gen control panel or the API enabled.

Comment: If I am not using an administrator account, is there any way i can retrieve the email contacts under Google Apps Directory in Google Apps Script?